# Is there anyway to embed a game from Coolmathgames.com to my site?

Tags: html, embed

Ive tried going through the code to find something to embed the game, some thing like this:

```
<iframe1 src="https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-ovo/play" class="square" width="800px" height="600px" id="html5game" scrolling="no"></iframe1>
```

But it dosnt work and i would like to embed games from cool math games onto my site
Like is there any way to get this game:https://coolmathgames.com/0-ovo or any game from this site: https://coolmathgames.com and embed it into a website

Comment: Doesnt work in what way? What does the console say? The website probably has the `X-Frame-Options` header set to `SAMEORIGIN` which means no one can iframe the site.

Comment: Can you go to https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-ovo/play and see if you can get the games raw html file or swf file, wich ever type it uses so i can embed the game and not the site itself, ive tried to go through the code looking for the main code but cant find it, if you know what i mean is like just the game file itself

Answer (score 0):

Or, do https://coolmathgames.com/0-ovo/play .  That also is fullscreen.

Comment: Dr. LEmon, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that if you inspect, then delete everything that doesn't keep the game running, then you can copy the html code from that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35326647)

Answer (score 0):

No, just do https://www.coolmathgames.com/sites/default/files/public_games/49389/
It's the only thing that can be "embeded" as an iframe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use the URL https://m.coolmathgames.com/0-ovo. The ‘m’ for ‘mobile’ makes it auto-fullscreen.